# Issue with uploading document to sharepoint libary

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-permissions

Was wondering if you guys have seen this error message before? We have an end user with a document that is trying to upload to a SharePoint site and get this error in the attached image. Any thoughts? They have uploaded things here in the past with no issues.

[image: Error Message that comes up when trying to load]

Comment: Has the user tried a hard refresh or logging out and logging back in?

Comment: do you know if any remote event receiver attached with this document library on Item Adding event?

Comment: What permissions are granted to user for this library?

Comment: Whether all users or one user occurs this issue? Whether all document library or one document library occurs this issue?